# Can I derive the number of days since Jan 1 1900 for a given `Date` using just the `java.*` API?

Tags: java, calendar, datetimeoffset

Spreadsheets (MS Excel, Google Apps) represent dates as the number of whole days since Jan 1 1900 (possibly [caveat a Feb 29 odditiy in Excel's case](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/exceldmy.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=4548&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=1036128)).  OK, so it's 365 days except on leap years.  But that's too much arithmetic already.

Presumably, `java.util.[Gregorian]Calendar` knows all this stuff.  The problem is, I don't know how to access it's knowledge.

In a speculative world, one might:

```
myGcalEarlier.set(1900, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
myGcalLater.set(new Date());

long days1 = myGcalEarlier.mysteryMethod();
long days2 = myGcalLater.mysteryMethod();

long days = days2 - days1;
```

Sadly, `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAYS_IN_YEAR)` doesn't satisfy for 'mysteryMethod' - it would need a `Calendar.DAYS_EVER` field to do what I want.

Is there an API for getting an accurate difference expressed in *calendar days*?

### Notes

I really do want calendar days, and not days-of-86400-seconds.  Time zones and daylight-savings matters aside (thanks @Dipmedeep), leap years need to be considered.  31536000 seconds is 365 days in these terms.  3 out of 4 years, that gets me from Jan 1 to Jan1. But on the 4th year, it only gets me from Jan 1 to Dec 31, giving me a 1-day error for every 4 years!

I [already have a solution for getting the number of calendar days](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/exceldmy.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=4548&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=1036128).  It's a trivial bit of code to migrate to Java, and it gets the desired answer (although I don't understand it, and therefore distrust it).  This question is specifically asking (now even moreso after editing) if I can at all avoid doing those calculations and defer it to a 'trusted' library in the JDK.  I have thus far concluded 'no'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty dumb and inefficient way of achieving your goal, but it could be used to validate other techniques

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
      //now.setTime(new Date()); // set the date you want to calculate the days for
      Calendar tmp = Calendar.getInstance();
      tmp.set(0,0,0); // init a temporary calendar.
      int days=0;
      // iterate from 1900 and check how many days are in the year, sum the days 
      for (int i=1900; i < now.get(Calendar.YEAR);i++) {
          tmp.set(Calendar.YEAR, i);
          int daysForThatYear = tmp.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
          days+=daysForThatYear;
          System.out.printf("year:%4d days in the year:%3d, total days:%6d\n",i,daysForThatYear,days);
      }
      // check the number of days for the current year, and add to the total of days
      int daysThisYear = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
      days+=daysThisYear;
      System.out.printf("year:%4d days in the year:%3d, total days:%6d\n",now.get(Calendar.YEAR),daysThisYear,days);
}
```

Comment: You nailed it, I think. Using fields and `getActualMaximum()` as you have done seems to be the intended way to *interrogate* the Calendar to give up its secret knowledge, even though it doesn't provide a *service* that calculates offsets for you. Given that we wanted to use Calendar's understanding of the calendar, your solution seems as efficient as we're likely to get using just `java.*`. Thanks for a thoughtful answer!

Answer (score -1):

Little knowledge about the specifics of java's date API here, but if you can find a method that gives you Unix timestamps, you should be able to figure it out - a Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since epoch (Jan 1st, 1970, 0:00:00 UTC), so all you need to do is find the Unix timestamps for both dates, subtract, divide by 86400 (the number of seconds in a day) and cut off the fractional part.

The same can be done for any other linear representation of the time points - all you need to know is how to convert to that linear representation, and how many units there are in a day.

Answer (score -1):

you may use `myGcalEarlier.getTimeInMillis()` and `myGcalLater.getTimeInMillis()` and then convert to days by dividing on milliseconds in a day count. 24*60*60*1000.
and your first set call is wrong.

```
set(int year, int month, int date)
```

month is 0-based 0 for january

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding the set(int,int,int) call.

Answer (score -1):

GregorianCalendar myGcalEarlier = new GregorianCalendar();
  GregorianCalendar myGcalLater = new GregorianCalendar();
  myGcalEarlier.set(1900, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);

long lTime1 = myGcalEarlier.getTimeInMillis();
  long lTime2 = myGcalLater.getTimeInMillis();

long days = (lTime2 - lTime1)/(24*60*60*1000);

Comment: You didn't read the question, or the other answers.  Your code gives the wrong result.